# interposers on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, dynamic-linking

Is it possible to substitute system functions, as is possible on Linux and Solaris using the LD_PRELOAD

For example by setting the environment variable:
LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/mymalloc.so

I would have my replacement malloc functions instead of in the C runtime already installed in the system libraries.  All other functions in the system dll's would run as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Research has a library called [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) which allows you to intercept Win32 API calls.

> Detours is a library for instrumenting arbitrary Win32 functions on x86, x64, and IA64 machines. Detours intercepts Win32 functions by re-writing the in-memory code for target functions. The Detours package also contains utilities to attach arbitrary DLLs and data segments (called payloads) to any Win32 binary.

Answer (score 1):

If Detours ( as mentioned previously ) is not an option - then you might take a look at [WinAPI Override](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/). It is actively mantained. 
Note that only 32 bit version is available.