# Why should we overload/override new and delete?

Tags: c++, memory-management, overloading, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any reason to overload global new and delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152511/any-reason-to-overload-global-new-and-delete)

Why should we overload/override new and delete in C++?

Give me an example of situation in which we should overload/override new, new[], delete or delete[].

Comment: And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-should-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like a homework assignment. Nevertheless, here are two uses off the top of my head:

- For profiling purposes. For instance, we use it in a library as a poor-man’s `valgrind` to track memory leaks.
- To implement a custom allocator (e.g. a pool allocator) for your objects. Usually I’d implement an `allocator` for this, though.

Comment: +1, for `poor-man’s valgrind` :))

Answer (score 0):

To provide your implementation of allocating/deallocating memory. new/delete are very general. When you know how your application is going to use memory you can provide more efficient version of new/delete. That would be very simple for example if you used a lot of small object.

Another usage would be to provide memory leak detection.

That's not very often used mechanism - at least in my experience.