# What is the benefit of overloading 'new' and 'delete' for custom memory allocation in game engines?

Tags: c++, memory-management, game-engine

I'm in the process of porting my game engine from Java to C++. I've been doing a lot of research on custom memory allocators as I now need to worry about memory management. Every article that I've read on the topic says that you should overload the `new` and `delete` operators. However, these overloaded operators usually just delegate to and call a custom function that handles the memory allocation. Furthermore, macros are commonly used such as:

```
#define New(className, size, description) customNew(className, size, description, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

which never even use the overloaded `new` operator, and simply calls the custom method. I understand how the macros are useful as you can get the filename and line numbers nicely, but why overload `new` and `delete` if in code you're simply going to use the macro `New` and not the operators.

Also, overriding (not overloading) the default `new` seems somewhat pointless when our custom allocator may want to know additional information such as a description, a filename and line numbers. We can't possibly know that information on a standard invocation of `new`and can't delegate it to our `customNew` in a meaningful way.

I'm failing to see what the great benefit is of overloading and overriding these operators.

It seems to me that calling:

```
customNew(className, size, desc, file, line);
```

is more intuitive than calling the overloaded `new`:

```
new (size, desc, file, line) className();
```

Finally, if I were to override and overload, where is the best place to do so? Doing it per class is obnoxiously tedious. Can it be done by namespace? I plan on having separate projects for each sub-system so that they can be maintained independently. How would I facilitate overriding and overloading across the projects and then within the game's project? Pardon my C++ n00bishness. It's been a while.

Comment: What is your purpose in wanting to provide these alternatives in the first place?

Comment: this is kind of a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149461/why-would-one-replace-default-new-and-delete-operators

Comment: If you want a separate memory allocator for each and every class, you *can* overload these. If you don't want to, just don't. ;-)

Comment: No, I don't want separate allocators for each class. I'd prefer to route every allocation through a single method/operator. My main question is WHERE should these methods/operators be defined, and WHAT is the difference between simply writing a custom method to allocate memory vs. overriding/loading `new` to use my custom method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm failing to see what the great benefit is of overloading and overriding these operators.

There's the obvious point: you can't escape it (not without work).

If you want all your memory allocation to go through one location, all it takes for someone to screw that up is this:

```
new Foo();
```

However, if you globally override operators `new` and `delete`, they have to do more work:

```
void * ptr = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
new(ptr) Foo;
```

There is also the point that the *vast* majority of C++ programmers are used to `new` and `delete`, which they will use by default. If you require them to use a function, that becomes something you have to teach them and they have to learn. And if they make a mistake and use the standard way, see above.

Oh, and then there's the syntax:

```
customNew(className, size, desc, file, line);
```

That's not going to work. That may allocate memory, but it will *not* construct a type. It is no different from `malloc`. So the very name is a lie; it's not "new"-ing anything. It's just allocating.

You would need to use C++11 variadic templates and in-place construction to do things correctly:

```
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
T *customNew<T>(const char *className, const char *desc, size_t file, size_t line, Args&&... args)
{
  void* ptr = allocate_memory(className, sizeof(T), desc, file, line);
  return new(ptr) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Personally, I'd say that the `new(...) T(...)` syntax is much cleaner than the `customNew<T>(...)` version. It's clear which parameters go to the allocator, and which parameters go to the type itself. It's certainly more *standard*.

> But WHERE do I override the global new and delete

*Globally*. As in the global namespace. You stick the overloads in a header somewhere and include it everywhere.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help. However, I still have one question about the usage of `new`. Suppose that I want to always use the overloaded version of `new` that has the extra information such as a description, filename, and line number parameters. Is there anything that I can do to enforce the usage of `new(size_t size, params...)`, or do I just need to record the "improper" usage of `new(size_t size)` and retroactively fix these bad allocations? Thanks.

Comment: @Wagan8r: You could make `new(size_t size)` assert or throw an exception.

Comment: @Nik-Lz: The example was of what you would have to do to avoid someone who globally override `new` and `delete`. So calling `::operator new` like that won't avoid that override; calling `malloc` will.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a general purpose allocator that is garbage collected, aligned, and has a maximum size limit, which might be possible constraints of your spec. If you use external code that makes use of new/delete, you could redirect requests to this allocator as some kind of low-level/system memory space.

Also, articles I read often go after the [global operators](http://www.swedishcoding.com/2008/08/31/are-we-out-of-memory/) as a start. Here is a good [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152511/any-reason-to-overload-global-new-and-delete) on the subject.

Comment: Yes, I've read that article multiple times, as well as this 4-part blog post http://jfdube.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/memory-management-part-1-introduction/. But WHERE do I override the global `new` and `delete` in addition to any overloads??