# Passing std::string as parameter from one DLL to another DLL throwing access violation error

Tags: c++, dll

The application has many C++ compiled DLLs, each exposing many C type interfaces. The application has some std::string type configuration variables which needs to be used in the DLL interface logic. While passing this std::string type parameters to these DLLs, "0xC0000005: Access violation executing location" has thrown. Is this something related to VS project settings for DLL projects? Kindly clarify.

Comment: Could be also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634773

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't make them to work easily.

`std::string` may not be compatible between different compilations from different libraries.

When you say "The application has many C++ compiled DLLs", very likely you're in this scenario:

**Library A:**

```
// STL
class std::string
{
    ... under the hood implementation of std::string (version A)
};

// Library code
std::string someFunctionInA();
```

**Library B:**

```
// STL
class std::string
{
    ... under the hood implementation of std::string (version B)
};

// Library code
void someFunctionInB(const std::string& myString);
```

**The crash program:**

```
std::string stringFromA = someFunctionInA();
someFunctionInB(stringFromA);
```

Got it? You have 2 versions of `std::string` and you program compiles because you're using the same headers during the compilations of your program... but in runtime, they are expecting 2 different types.

Size of the objects, order of data and simply the allocators may not match... and it will crash!

How to resolve:

- if you can compile from source, make sure you use the same STL version.
- if you can't compile from source, create C wrappers for them and use C-String as interface... they will always work.

Comment: I am using same header file for std::string during compile and runtime.