# Memory allocation problem C/Cpp Windows critical error

Tags: c++, windows, memory, allocation

I have a code that need to be "translated" from C to Cpp, and i cant understand, where's a problem. There is the part, where it crashes (windows critical error send/dontSend):

```
 nDim = sizeMax*(sizeMax+1)/2;
 printf("nDim  = %d sizeMax = %d\n",nDim,sizeMax);
 hamilt = (double*)malloc(nDim*sizeof(double));
 printf("End hamilt alloc. %d allocated\n",(nDim*sizeof(double)));
 transProb = (double*)malloc(sizeMax*sizeMax*sizeof(double));
 printf("End transProb alloc. %d allocated\n",(sizeMax*sizeMax*sizeof(double)));
 eValues = (double*)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double));
 printf("eValues allocated. %d allocated\n",(sizeMax*sizeof(double)));
    eVectors  = (double**)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double*));
 printf("eVectors allocated. %d allocated\n",(sizeMax*sizeof(double*)));
 if(eVectors) for(i=0;i<sizeMax;i++) {
                 eVectors[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double));
                 printf("eVectors %d-th element allocated. %d allocated\n",i,(sizeMax*sizeof(double)));
                 }
 eValuesPrev = (double*)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double));
 printf("eValuesPrev allocated. %d allocated\n",(sizeMax*sizeof(double)));
 eVectorsPrev  = (double**)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double*));
 printf("eVectorsPrev allocated. %d allocated\n",(sizeMax*sizeof(double*)));
 if(eVectorsPrev) for(i=0;i<sizeMax;i++) {
                     eVectorsPrev[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeMax*sizeof(double));
                     printf("eVectorsPrev %d-th element allocated. %d allocated\n",i,(sizeMax*sizeof(double)));
                     }
```

Log:

```
nDim  = 2485 sizeMax = 70
End hamilt alloc. 19880 allocated
End transProb alloc. 39200 allocated
eValues allocated. 560 allocated
eVectors allocated. 280 allocated
```

So it crashes at the start of the loop of allocation. If i delete this loop it crashes at the next line of allocation. Does it mean that with the numbers like this i have not enough memory??

Thank you.

Comment: argh.. better formatting please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, this program compiles, executes without error and reports no memory problems when run through valgrind. Unless you are running on a small embedded system, your problem is likely something external to this code, because the total amount of memory allocated by this program is less than 140 KiB.

Besides, when `malloc` fails, it doesn't crash, it returns NULL. This code properly checks for `eVectorsPrev` being NULL, so there should be no NULL dereferencing problems here.

Comment: >>is less than 140 KiB.

exactly. Actually, before this there are some mallocation, but of the more or less same sizes. Tell me, please, are there some possibilities to see if i am out of memory? Or how can i "catch" the reason of the crash? 

And one more: i ve just noticed that the C-version is normally compiled by the same compiler of my DevC++ despite having the lines like 
 hamilt = malloc(nDim*sizeof(double));
without precision the type. Is it normal? Or i have occasion some strange compiler settings?

Comment: The variables like `hamilt` must have their type declared *somewhere* otherwise it would not compile. They may be parameters of the function or globals. To detect memory corruption problems (which is what this most likely is) and/or to get a read on how much memory is being used, use a memory profiler/debugger. I use valgrind, but that's on Linux. This post has some good suggestions for valgrind-like tools for windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: yeah, the types are declared before. But what seems strange for me is that i was not able to compile the new version (also given to me on C) before precising the type for each malloc. But the previous one compiles. Where can be a difference?

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the casts of `(double*)`, etc. on the `malloc` calls. In C this can be left out since `malloc` returns `void*` which implicitly converts to any pointer type. C++, being a different language, requires that you do an explicit conversion. However in C++, you really should be using `new[]` instead of `malloc`, or if you are going to use `malloc`, at least use `static_cast` instead of the C-style casts you posted.

Comment: @andrew: heap corruption occurs at points sometimes very distant from the code that signals the corruption; adding new code can disclose heap corruption that happened in some completely unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not trying to allocate too much memory. Some other code has likely [corrupted the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors) and that can bite at just about any arbitrary point in the code afterwards. See the link for debugging aids.

If you were out of memory in a defect free program, malloc would return an error indication.

Answer (score 0):

What is `sizeMax`? I do not see the declaration, please fix the formatting. A side note... you are blindingly calling `malloc` without checking if it worked or not...that is a dangerous assumption - never assume there is plenty of memory available as the heap could become very fragmented and when a call to `malloc` for a very small object in a fragmented heap could fail as there is not enough memory...