# How to debug nondeterministic access violation crash?

Tags: c#, c++, com, crash, access-violation

Our C#/COM/C++ application is crashing and I need help debugging it. Running with gflags enabled and WinDbg attached, we determined the crashes are caused by an access violation, but we haven't been able to narrow it down any more than that. We are not seeing the issue on all machines; there are a couple of machines that seem to reproduce the issue frequently but not deterministically. We have observed the application crash from simply switching away from the application (say, Alt-Tab) and then back. Output from WinDbg is below.

We have been trying to systematically comment out areas of code that could be causing the problem, but we haven't had much success yet.

Any suggestions on what debugging steps or tools we should try?

> !analyze -v
>
> EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr
>   0xffffffffffffffff) ExceptionAddress:
>   1a584ff2
>   (+0x1a584ff1)
>   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access
>   violation)   ExceptionFlags: 00000000
>   NumberParameters: 2    Parameter[0]:
>   00000000    Parameter[1]: 1a584ff2
>   Attempt to read from address 1a584ff2
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  ProcessFiles.exe
>
> ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 -
>   The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced
>   memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could
>   not be %s.
>
> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005
>   - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The
>   memory could not be %s.
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000000
>
> EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  1a584ff2
>
> READ_ADDRESS:  1a584ff2
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  Ed20+1a584ff1 1a584ff2
>   ??              ???
>
> NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000000
>
> APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0
>
> IP_MODULE_UNLOADED:  Ed20+1a584ff1
>   1a584ff2 ??              ???
>
> MANAGED_STACK:  (TransitionMU)
>   0EC6F6F4 7B1D8CCE
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32,
>   Int32, Int32)+0x24e 0EC6F790 7B1D8937
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)+0x177
>   0EC6F7E4 7B1D8781
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)+0x61
>   0EC6F814 7B195911
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)+0x31
>   0EC6F828 0969D97A
>   Extract_Utilities_Forms!Extract.Utilities.Forms.VerificationForm`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].A(System.Object)+0x23a
>   0EC6F8C0 79A00EEE
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)+0x72a25e
>   0EC6F8CC 792E019F
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback,
>   System.Object)+0x6f 0EC6F8E4 797DB48A
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)+0x4a
>   (TransitionUM)
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7e418734
>   to 1a584ff2
>
> FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff
>
> ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set
>   based on attribute [ip_not_executable]
>   from Frame:[0] on thread:[e30]
>
> BUGCHECK_STR: 
>   APPLICATION_FAULT_BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_WINDOW_HOOK
>
> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS: 
>   BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID: 
>   BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR
>
> STACK_TEXT:   7b1d8cce
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop+0xc
>   7b1d8937
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner+0x0 7b1d8781
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop+0x0
>   7b195911
>   System_Windows_Forms_ni!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run+0x31
>   0969d97a
>   Extract_Utilities_Forms!Extract.Utilities.Forms.VerificationForm`1[[System.__Canon,
>   mscorlib]].A+0x23a 79a00eee
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context+0x72a25e
>   792e019f
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x6f
>   797db48a
>   mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart+0x4a
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  .ecxr ; ~~[e30] ;
>   .frame 0 ; ** Pseudo Context ** ; kb
>
> FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
>   Ed20+1a584ff1 1a584ff2 ??
>   ???
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  Ed20
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner
>
> MODULE_NAME: Ed20
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  Ed20
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 
>   BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_c0000005_Ed20!Unloaded
>
> BUCKET_ID: 
>   APPLICATION_FAULT_BAD_INSTRUCTION_PTR_INVALID_POINTER_READ_WRONG_SYMBOLS_WINDOW_HOOK_BAD_IP_Ed20
>
> Followup: MachineOwner

Comment: Have you tried running attached to the debugger with first chance exception handling enabled?  (Ctrl+Alt+E in Visual Studio).

Comment: Yes, and what's strange is: we don't see anything. It only seems to be reproducible on a couple machines, not our development machines.

Comment: The heap is corrupted.  You'll find good debugging hints in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors or by googling "how to debug heap corruption".

Answer (score 3):

Find a computer that reproduces the crash fairly often, and install WinDbg on that computer. Then run `windbg.exe -I`, which will make WinDbg the post-mortem crash handler.

Wait for the crash to occur. When that happens, WinDbg will automatically open at the point of the crash. Use the WinDbg command `kpn` to get a stack trace. (You may need to ensure that you have symbols on the machine, too.)

Comment: I've pre-attached `windbg.exe` in the past and tried to configure it to not break overly often, but I didn't know about the `-I` switch and this seems like a much cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

We ended up finding the problem by evaluating all code changes since the last version of the software (which didn't crash). The culprit was that HideSelection was being set to false in the OnLostFocus override of a text control. Per [this](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/18884) post-- that causes bad things to happen (well, on some machines, anyway).