# Assertion failure when deleting array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using following code:

```
int main () {
    wchar_t *serial = new wchar_t[1];
    wchar_t *user = new wchar_t[1];
    size_t strLen;

    do {
        wprintf (L"Username (between 4 and 30 characters): ");
        wscanf (L"%ls", user);
    } while ((strLen = wcslen (user)) < 4 || strLen > 30);

    wprintf (L"Serial key: ");
    wscanf (L"%ls", serial);

    std::getchar ();
    std::getchar (); // Twice, because of trailing \n of wscanf()

    delete[] serial; // Error!
    delete[] user;

    return 0;
}
```

Everytime I'm getting an assertion failure. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755002/debug-assertion-failed) I read that I have to use `delete[]` instead of `delete`, if I want to deallocate arrays. So I corrected my code and was still getting the exact same error. In [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/1bdc8f9d-885c-4abb-93a3-7d43fe88efb0/delete-operator-generating-debug-assertion-failed-error) forum I read that the pointer that I want to delete mustn't change. I checked my pointer with `cout << (int)serial;` and the printed number wasn't changing. **How to deallocate an array?** Everytime I use `delete` (no matter when/where) I get assertion failures. Am I making something wrong?

Comment: A null-terminated serial key and username between 4 and 30 characters most certainly do not fit in one character. Use `std::wstring`, not `wchar_t *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are deallocating the memory, the problem is with the way you are allocating and using it:

```
wchar_t *serial = new wchar_t[1];
wchar_t *user = new wchar_t[1];
```

You have allocated just one char for each variable. The number between `[]` is how many elements to allocate, in this case how many `wchar_t`s.

What happens is that there is nothing stopping the user from writing a lot more chars into `user[]/serial[]` on the calls to:

```
wscanf (L"%ls", user); 
wscanf (L"%ls", serial);
```

`wscanf` doesn't do bounds checking on the array. If the user writes more than 1 char in the terminal, `wscanf` will be writing outside the bounds of the arrays, corrupting the memory space of your program and triggering an assertion when that memory is later deallocated and consequently validated by `delete[]`.

**Suggested fix:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring serial;
    std::wstring user;
    size_t strLen = 0;

    do {

        std::wcout << L"Username (between 4 and 30 characters): ";
        std::wcin >> user;

    } while ((strLen = user.length()) < 4 || strLen > 30);

    std::wcout << L"Serial key: ";
    std::wcin >> serial;

    std::getchar();

    std::wcout << L"User....: " << user   << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Serial..: " << serial << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Avoid using raw pointers if possible by using `std::string` and `std::wstring`. Also, prefer `std::cout` and `std::wcout` for terminal/console IO.

Comment: A pointer to use `std::wstring` instead of `wchar_t*` would be nice.

Comment: I forgot that I was using 1 element. This was a test from before my current project. I wanted to find out when the assertion failure occurs, because it seemed to occur randomly. With 1 element it was more everytime than randomly. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, added suggested implementation using `std::wstring` instead.

Comment: @Cubinator73, make sure to take a look at my suggested fix and possibly switch to strings. They are always preferred over raw pointers when in C++.

Comment: @glampert I'm definitely going to do this :)