# Why would fclose hang / deadlock? (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, deadlock, fclose

I have a directory change monitor process that reads updates from files within a set of directories. I have another process that performs small writes to a lot of files to those directories (test program). Figure about 100 directories with 10 files in each, and about 500 files being modified per second.

After running for a while, the directory monitor process hangs on a call to `fclose()` in a method that is basically tailing the file. In this method, I `fopen()` the file, check that the handle is valid, do a few seeks and reads, and then call `fclose()`. These reads are all performed by the same thread in the process. After the hang, the thread never progresses.

I couldn't find any good information on why `fclose()` might deadlock instead of returning some kind of error code. The documentation does mention `_fclose_nolock()`, but it doesn't seem to be available to me (Visual Studio 2003).

The hang occurs for both debug and release builds. In a debug build, I can see that `fclose()` calls `_free_base()`, which hangs before returning. Some kind of call into kernel32.dll => ntdll.dll => KernelBase.dll => ntdll.dll is spinning. Here's the assembly from ntdll.dll that loops indefinitely:

```
77CEB83F  cmp         dword ptr [edi+4Ch],0 
77CEB843  lea         esi,[ebx-8] 
77CEB846  je          77CEB85E 
77CEB848  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi+50h] 
77CEB84B  xor         dword ptr [esi],eax 
77CEB84D  mov         al,byte ptr [esi+2] 
77CEB850  xor         al,byte ptr [esi+1] 
77CEB853  xor         al,byte ptr [esi] 
77CEB855  cmp         byte ptr [esi+3],al 
77CEB858  jne         77D19A0B 
77CEB85E  mov         eax,200h 
77CEB863  cmp         word ptr [esi],ax 
77CEB866  ja          77CEB815 
77CEB868  cmp         dword ptr [edi+4Ch],0 
77CEB86C  je          77CEB87E 
77CEB86E  mov         al,byte ptr [esi+2] 
77CEB871  xor         al,byte ptr [esi+1] 
77CEB874  xor         al,byte ptr [esi] 
77CEB876  mov         byte ptr [esi+3],al 
77CEB879  mov         eax,dword ptr [edi+50h] 
77CEB87C  xor         dword ptr [esi],eax 
77CEB87E  mov         ebx,dword ptr [ebx+4] 
77CEB881  lea         eax,[edi+0C4h] 
77CEB887  cmp         ebx,eax 
77CEB889  jne         77CEB83F
```

Any ideas what might be happening here?

Comment: My money is on a heap corruption. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your monitoring process's source code?

Comment: What parameters are you using in fopen? What filesystem are you using? Which OS Version? Which runtime library (MT/ST)? Is DCOM involved (Apartment Model)?

Comment: @Jens: Opening with "rb". Filesystem is NTFS, remote share. Processes are running on Windows 7. Runtime library is MD / MDd. DCOM is not involved.

Comment: @aix: Sorry, I can't post the code. Heap corruption does sound like a possibility; I'll look into it.

Comment: As you are using MD libraries, I think, you are deadlocking in a CriticalSection. Try using the single threaded libraries to avoid deadlocking. If the monitor program is simple enough, you can perhaps solve all concurrency issues for yourself.

Comment: @Jens - If it really is looping in the assembly code that was excerpted, I really doubt this has anything to do with a critical section.  There are no atomic instructions here.  It looks plausible that this assembly code is traversing a linked list, possibly some internal data structure for the heap. (A free list?  A list of outstanding allocations?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this as a comment, but I realize this could be an answer in its own right...

Based on the disassembly, my guess is you've overwritten some internal heap structure maintained by `ntdll`, and it is looping forever iterating through a linked list.

In particular at the start of the loop, the current list node seems to be in `ebx`.  At the end of the loop, the expected last node (or terminator, if you like -- it looks a bit like these are circular lists and the last node is the same as the first, pointer to this node being at `[edi+4Ch]`) is contained in `eax`.  Probably the result of `cmp ebx, eax` is never equal, because there is some cycle in the list introduced by a heap corruption.

I don't think this has anything to do with locks, otherwise we would see some atomic instructions (eg. `lock cmpxchg`, `xchg`, etc.) or calls to other synchronization functions.

Comment: It did turn out to be a heap corruption issue. aix pointed this out almost immediately, but I'll mark this as the answer for actually tracing through the disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same case with file close function. In my case, I solved by located the close function embedded other function body instead of having own function.

I was also suspicious on 
(1) the name of file being duplicated (2) Windows scheduling (file IO wasn't completed before next task treading being started. Windows scheduling and multi-threading is behind of the curtain, so it is hard to verify, but I have similar issue when I tried to save many data in ASCII in the loop. Saving on binary solved at this case.)

My environment, IDE: Visual Studio 2015, OS: Windows 7, language: C++