# How to debug heap corruption on armv5

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, valgrind, heap-corruption

I am on linux on an embedded device.
My architecture is armv5.

My fairly large (~30kloc) has some kind of heap corruption that happens over time.

I cannot run valgrind since my arch is not supported.
I can only run a limited gdb since my app uses thread and the corruption most probably happens in one of the thread.

I get

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread
>   library, thread debugging will not be available.

libthread_db and libpthread come from my gnueabi toolchain.

I was wondering what was the best course of actions now. Should I keep trying to get libthread_db to work with gdb? Or is there some other tool like valgrind that I could use?

Comment: Can a) port the code to your desktop OS and valgrind it there, or b) replace global `new` and track allocations?

Comment: How can I replace global new?

Comment: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30642&seqNum=3

Comment: @Eric: [Here's a start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421791#4421791). [Here's more.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194127/how-should-i-write-iso-c-standard-conformant-custom-new-and-delete-operators/)

Answer (score 3):

> warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

This error means that GDB attempted to `dlopen` every `libthread_db.so.1` from `libthread-db-search-path` (use `show libthread-db-search-path` to see what that is), and all versions of `libthread_db.so.1` failed to work with `libpthread` that you have on the target (your embedded device).

Most likely your `libthread-db-search-path` is simply incorrect.

Another possibility is that your toolchain shipped (say) `i686-linux` version of `libthread_db.so.1`, but you are using GDB built for `x86_64-linux`. 64-bit GDB (obviously) can't dlopen 32-bit `libthread_db`.

Even if you manage to set up multi-threaded debugging properly (which you should try in any case), it is quite unlikely that that will help you find heap corruption problem: usually by the time you get a crash due to heap corruption, all traces of code that actually caused it have disappeared.

If you are using `glibc` on target, `MALLOC_CHECK_=2` might help. Documentation [here](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html).

If you are using some other `libc`, it may have similar malloc debugging facilities. Or you could try one of the [many](http://dmalloc.com/) [debug](http://code.google.com/p/google-perftools/) [mallocs](http://www.canonware.com/download/jemalloc/jemalloc-latest/doc/jemalloc.html) available.

Comment: I am aware of the libthread-db-search-path config, but it does not solve my problem unfortunately. Both my toolchain and gdb run on my device, I've cross compiled gdb with the said toolchain

Comment: Also I am using C++ so I don't have any mallocs, only news. Is this still going to work?

Comment: My bet with gdb was to check for the memory location of a particular variable getting overwritten then setting a memory watch on that location. Might or might not work...

Answer (score 1):

[The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors) have very good guidelines. I would give electricfence a run.
[This paper](http://www.parl.clemson.edu/~wjones/summerStudents/memoryDebugging/pres.pdf) is also very informative(even if it talks\uses valgrind).