# Heap issue using "maximize speed" but not with "minimize size"

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, heap-memory, release

I'm debugging a dll generating a heap issue. I'm working with heap page enabled. Trying many versions of that dll, debug works, release minimum size works but release maximize speed fails.

I know some differences between debug and release so I'm checking possible initialization issues. But can the fact that my dll works in release minimize size but not in release maximum size could give me a little more information about what type of mistake I made ?

What are the main differences differences between the two binaries produced ? (excluding executable size and execution speed of course).

P.S. : my dll contains many QT widgets. I don't know if it could help, but if there are commonly made mistakes with these objects...

Comment: Without code your solution is likely to be impossible to solve; only broad (obvious) tips can be given.

Comment: What is your error message ? © What's the state of the stack when your  issue is happening ? Could be a double delete or a buffer overrun ?

Answer (score 3):

A general answer for a general question: It sounds like there may be some sort of memory corruption going on. One of the difficulties of finding, or even detecting, memory corruption is that its symptoms may appear/disappear with just small changes of the code. This includes debug/release builds and various release optimizations.

The answer to [How to debug heap corruption errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors) gives a great overview on debugging memory corruption.