# Heap corruption in MFC program

Tags: c++, mfc, heap-corruption

I am having a problem with a heap corruption issue in a program. In the program I am reading a block of data and performing FFT and IFFT on it. I am doing it for 2 images, master and slave. The EXACT same code works fine for the master but shows a heap corruption for the slave file when I try to delete the slave buffer.

fcomplex is defined as:

```
typedef struct {float real, imag;}fcomplex;
```

A snippet of relevant parts of the code is attached:
Full code: http://sharetext.org/7xXe

The error does not occur if I do not call the fft and ifft functions for the slave image. (Everything works fine for the master though)

To debug the error I installed Application verifier but I was not able to decode the log file. Its here: http://sharetext.org/Y2ji (XML file copy pasted)

The error visual studio give is:
Heap corruption Detected: after normal block (#194456) at 0x062C0040

```
CCoarseFun::fcomplex * slave_bfr;
CCoarseFun::fcomplex * slave_col;


slave_bfr = Pcoarse.init_1Dcmplx(SIZE*s_cols); 
slave_col = Pcoarse.init_1Dcmplx(SIZE);

Pcoarse.cfft1d_(&SIZE,slave_col,&FFTdir); // This function causes a problem
Pcoarse.complex_mult_col(filter, slave_col, SIZE, slave_col)
Pcoarse.cfft1d_(&SIZE,slave_col,&FFTdir); // As does this one

// delete memory related to slave
delete [] slave_bfr;    // Heap corruption here
delete [] slave_col;
```

What is baffleing me is that the code is pretty simple and it works 100% for only the master files. Why is it crashing for the slave?

Can some one guide me to a solution or maybe a tutorial on how to use the Application verifier as well?

Thanks,
Shaunak

EDIT: Using Win7 x64 - VS2010

EDIT 2: Definition for init_1Dcmplx

```
CCoarseFun::fcomplex* CCoarseFun::init_1Dcmplx(int n)
{
  fcomplex *a;
  a=new fcomplex[n];
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    a[i].real=float(0.0);
    a[i].imag=float(0.0);
  }
  return a;
}
```

EDIT3: COde for cfft1D_ : http://sharetext.org/hzIg

EDIT4: Code for mem.delfloat()

```
void CMemAlloc::del_float(float *a)
{
  if (a!=NULL)
  {
    delete[] a;
    a=NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `init_1Dcmplx` defined? Does it use `new ...[]` to allocate the structures?

Comment: @nneonneo Yes. Please see EDIT2

Comment: Post the code for cfft1d_, it is the relevant part.

Comment: @lyricat http://sharetext.org/hzIg

Comment: What is the code for `mem.del_float()`?

Comment: BTW, why does `cfft1d_()` take pointers to integers? They seem to be just input parameters.

Comment: @LuboAntonov EDIT 4 - if(a!=NULL)
 {
 delete[] a;
 a=NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  return;
 }

Comment: @LuboAntonov - The fft functions were written by some one else. The documentation only said that it took pointers. I cant explain why.

Comment: Can you post the actual definition? The parameter declarations are important for this one.

Comment: @LuboAntonov - void cfft1d_(int *np, fcomplex *c, int *dir);

Comment: No, I meant the 'del_float' function.

Comment: @LuboAntonov void del_float(float* a); - Thanks for trying to help BTW. Im very badly stuck

Comment: Well, del_float is not quite correct. It is deleting the array alright, but it is not setting the pointer back to NULL, like it seems. That's because it is operating on a copy of the pointer. But the pointer is not used after, so I don't think that's the ultimate cause.

Comment: @LuboAntonov Should i simply replace that with a delete statement instead? Please do post an answer, so if its correct, I can credit you for it. :)

Comment: You can try, in any case it needs to be fixed - but I think it is something else.

Comment: @LuboAntonov - replacing it with a delete [] statement causes no ill effects I can perceive, so I did it. Doesnt solve the problem though

Comment: Not solving your problem, but maybe of interest for you: You can always delete a null ptr, `delete` allows this (other than `free`), so no need to check it. And setting a to `NULL` in `del_float` is only setting a local variable, which is destroyed upon return, so has no real effect.

Comment: @WernerHenze - Thanks for the info. As you can see im very new to this and to top that, the old code was written by someone apparently as new as I am. Every bit of info helps.

Comment: cfft1d_ doesn't need to take np and dir as pointers. they should just be 'int's.  Every time you use a pointer unnecessarily, a fairy dies ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mem_float() function is not correct. It looks like it is setting the pointer to NULL after the delete, but it is only working on a copy of the pointer, so the caller's copy is still pointing to deleted memory block.

You can just do

```
delete [] cf;
cf = NULL;
```

You have a couple of lines that look like this:

```
four1(cf-1,nn,isign);
```

I think this is accessing memory before the beginning of the array.

Beyond this, the indexing inside `four1()` is insanely complicated - you will have to step through it with the debugger to check the edge cases.

Comment: I will look into its behavior. This function however works perfectly well the first call, for the master file though. And thank you so much for your continued help.

Comment: Nevermind, I was wrong about the indexing, I've removed that part.

Comment: I am look to see what changes I can do to that function. I do not see the problem though: The function initializes cf for 2*n values [say 32]. "i" will go till 30, so the index 31 will be valid. The constraint on n is that it must be a power of 2, so the code will be valid IMO. edit: Sorry ! did not see your update

Comment: Sorry! I typed that as you posted the edit! Il look into the new issue. F11'ing :)

Comment: Changing that too four1(cf,nn,isign) gives a new heap error. But I think this solution is correct, and at-least points me in the right direction. I may not be able to debug the fft code just yet. Can I work around it in some way?

Comment: Well, just changing the `cf-1` parameter will create problems in the `four1()` function (it is now probably accessing beyond the end of cf), which is why I was suggesting you debug it. You can also figure it out with pen and paper, since you know the actual values for the parameters.

Comment: Inside the function - for (i=1;i<n;i+=2) - since i is indexed from 1, it may not be overwriting memory before the array. I cant figure out why it should work like this though. Also slave_bfr is never passed to the fft function. I dont know why it is also causing a corruption.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it's important to understand what the heap corruption error is telling you.  When you run a Debug build in Visual Studio it uses the Debug version of the run-time library which has a debug heap.  Whenever you allocate some memory with `new` there are some extra guard bytes either side of it.  When you `delete` it the debug heap checks that those guard bytes are intact, and if not then it issues this warning.

Assuming that `Pcoarse.init_1Dcmplx()` allocates memory on the heap then the two calls to it will most likely allocate memory one after the other:

```
XXXXXX - guard bytes
slave_bfr
XYXYXY - these are the guard bytes that are probably being corrupted
slave_cols
XXXXXX
```

You perform the operation `Pcoarse.cfft1d_()` on `slave_cols` but then you get the heap corruption error when deleting `slave_bfr`.  This suggests that `cfft1d_()` is overwriting memory before the start of `slave_cols` so that it's corrupting the guard bytes of `slave_bfr`.

So I would look through your code for `cfft1d_()` for places where you might have negative array indexes as this could cause the memory in `slave_bfr` to be stomped on.

Also check some of the [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010106/how-to-debug-heap-corruption-errors) with useful tips on how to make the most of the debug heap, in particular [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8858707/188414) about how to enable more intensive memory checks.

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. I am trying to debug this via the links you have provided and suggestions from others on this page

Comment: This occurs even if I simply call the slave sequence also

Answer (score 0):

"Heap corruption Detected: after normal block (#194456) at 0x062C0040" says that you allocated a block, got the block #194456 with address 0x062C0040 and you wrote more memory bytes than you allocated. So you have a classical buffer overflow. You should consider replacing pointers with STL containers. In your case I'ld prefer using `std::vector` over a raw float array allocated with `new float[]`. The STL containers can help you detect writing beyond boundaries immediately at the wrong access, not only after deleting the memory block.

Comment: I personally would have liked to, since im not very comfortable with pointers / raw arrays, but all the old code uses that structure, inclusive of functions that i need to call like fft etc. Maybe I can try allocating a bigger block - or my allocation size is wrong, because code runs flawlessly for master.

Comment: If i replace slave_bfr = Pcoarse.init_1Dcmplx(SIZE*s_cols) with slave_bfr = Pcoarse.init_1Dcmplx(SIZE*s_cols+1) it does not give me any errors. But I have a 30mb chunk left after the delete statement.