# Immediate detection of heap corruption errors on Windows. How?

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory, heap-corruption, virtualalloc

I can't sleep! :)

I have a reasonably large project on Windows and encountered some heap corruption issues. I have read all SO, including this nice topic: [How to debug heap corruption errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1010106/1065190), however nothing was suitable to help me out-of-the-box. `Debug CRT` and `BoundsChecker` detected heap corruptions, but addresses were always different and detections point were always far away from the actual memory overwrites. I have not slept till the middle of the night and crafted the following hack:

```
DWORD PageSize = 0;

inline void SetPageSize()
{
    if ( !PageSize )
    {
        SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
        GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
        PageSize = sysInfo.dwPageSize;
    }
}

void* operator new (size_t nSize)
{
    SetPageSize();
    size_t Extra = nSize % PageSize;
    nSize = nSize + ( PageSize - Extra );
    return Ptr = VirtualAlloc( 0, nSize, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
}

void operator delete (void* pPtr)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    VirtualQuery(pPtr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    // leave pages in reserved state, but free the physical memory
    VirtualFree(pPtr, 0, MEM_DECOMMIT);
    DWORD OldProtect;
    // protect the address space, so noone can access those pages
    VirtualProtect(pPtr, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_NOACCESS, &OldProtect);
}
```

Some heap corruption errors became obvious and i was able to fix them. There were no more Debug CRT warnings on exit. However, i have some questions regarding this hack:

**1.** Can it produce any false positives?

**2.** Can it miss some of the heap corruptions? (even if we replace malloc/realloc/free?)

**3.** It fails to run on 32-bits with `OUT_OF_MEMORY`, only on 64-bits. Am I right we simply run out of the virtual address space on 32-bits?

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the [PageHeap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561(v=vs.85).aspx) GFLAGs? See [Detecting Heap Corruption Using GFlags and Dumps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx)

Comment: @Remus Rusanu: geat link! I would love to have it 24 hours ago :)

Comment: Next time you'll know :)

Comment: While it will catch reuse-after-free errors, do note that allocating any kind of object (say, 4 bytes in size) will take away 64kiB from your address space, because that is the minimum allocation granularity that Windows will do. This is the reason why it fails with OUT_OF_MEMORY under 32 bits, too -- it's the pretty much worst thing to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can it produce any false positives?

So, this will only catch bugs of the class "use after free()". For that purpose, I think, it's reasonably good.

If you try to `delete` something that wasn't `new`'ed, that's a different type of bug. In `delete` you should first check if the memory has been indeed allocated. You shouldn't be blindly freeing the memory and marking it as inaccessible. I'd try to avoid that and report (by, say, doing a debug break) when there's an attempt to `delete` something that shouldn't be deleted because it was never `new`'ed.

> Can it miss some of the heap corruptions? (even if we replace malloc/realloc/free?)

Obviously, this won't catch all corruptions of heap data between `new` and and the respective `delete`. It will only catch those attempted after `delete`.

E.g.:

```
myObj* = new MyObj(1,2,3);
// corruption of *myObj happens here and may go unnoticed
delete myObj;
```

> It fails to run on 32-bit target with OUT_OF_MEMORY error, only on 64-bit. Am I right that we simply run out of the virtual address space on 32-bits?

Typically you have available about ~2GB of the virtual address space on a 32-bit Windows. That's good for at most ~524288 `new`'s like in the provided code. But with objects bigger than 4KB, you'll be able to successfully allocate fewer instances than that. And then address space fragmentation will reduce that number further.

It's a perfectly expected outcome if you create many object instances during the life cycle of your program.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration! And nice to meet you here, Sir! I was learning 3D graphics starting from your pascal/asm 3D engines :)

Answer (score 6):

This won't catch:

- use of uninitialized memory (once your pointer is allocated, you can read garbage from it at will)
- buffer overruns (unless you overrun the PageSize boundary)

Ideally, you should write a well-known bit pattern before and after your allocated blocks, so that `operator delete` can check whether they were overwritten (indicated buffer over- or under-run).

Currently this would be allowed silently in your scheme, and switching back to `malloc` etc. would allow it to *silently* damage the heap, and show up as an error later on (eg. when freeing the block after the over-run one).

You can't catch everything though: note for example that if the underlying problem is  (valid) pointer somewhere getting overwritten with garbage, you can't detect this until the damaged pointer is de-referenced.

Comment: Catching buffer overruns in a deferred way is no problem - debug CRT can do it. Do you have any ideas how to improve this method to catch buffer overruns instantly?

Comment: Really, I think you either need access to hardware watchpoints or some clever memory protection trick (and ideally the ability to handle the trap). Valgrind, on the other hand, essentially does it by _interpreting_ the program so it can intercept every read & write.

Comment: "buffer overruns" - once in a while I addresses this problem by using custom allocator that allocates in a specific that last byte of the payload is exactly last byte on the page, and next page was a guard page hitting the access violation exception, that worked pretty well for an overrun - [Hardware assisted memory corruption detection](http://alax.info/blog/1319).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your current answer can miss heap corruptions of **buffer** **under-** and **overruns**. 

Your *delete()* function is pretty good!

I implemented a *new()* function in similar manner, that adds guard pages both for under- and overruns. 
From **GFlags** documentation I conclude that it protects only against overruns.

Note that when returning simply a pointer next to the underrun guard page then guard page for overruns is likely to be located away from the allocated object and **immediate vicinity** after the allocated object is **NOT guarded**. 

To compensate for this one would need to return such a pointer that the object is located immediately before overrun guard page (in this case again an underrun is less likely to be detected).

The below code does one or the other alternately for each call of *new()*. Or one might want to modify it to use threadsafe random generator instead to prevent any interferences with code calling the *new()*.

Considering all this one should be aware that detecting under- and overruns by the below code is still probabilistic to a degree - this is especially relevant in the case when some objects are allocated only once for the entire duration of the program.

**NB!** Because *new()* returns a modified aadress, the *delete()* function also had to be adjusted a bit, so it now uses *mbi.AllocationBase* instead of *ptr* for *VirtualFree()* and *VirtualProtect()*.

PS. *[Driver Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545470(v=vs.85).aspx)'s* [Special Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551832(v=vs.85).aspx) uses similar tricks.

```
volatile LONG priorityForUnderrun = rand(); //NB! init with rand so that the pattern is different across program runs and different checks are applied to global singleton objects

void ProtectMemRegion(void* region_ptr, size_t sizeWithGuardPages)
{
    size_t preRegionGuardPageAddress = (size_t)region_ptr;
    size_t postRegionGuardPageAddress = (size_t)(region_ptr) + sizeWithGuardPages - PageSize;   

    DWORD flOldProtect1;
    BOOL preRegionProtectSuccess = VirtualProtect(
        (void*)(preRegionGuardPageAddress),
        pageSize,
        PAGE_NOACCESS,
        &flOldProtect1  
    );

    DWORD flOldProtect2;
    BOOL postRegionProtectSuccess = VirtualProtect(
        (void*)(postRegionGuardPageAddress),
        PageSize,
        PAGE_NOACCESS,
        &flOldProtect2  
    );
}   

void* operator new (size_t size)
{
    size_t sizeWithGuardPages = (size + PageSize - 1) / PageSize * PageSize + 2 * PageSize;

    void* ptr = VirtualAlloc
    (
        NULL,
        sizeWithGuardPages,
        MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
        PAGE_READWRITE
    );

    if (ptr == NULL)    //NB! check for allocation failures
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    ProtectMemRegion(ptr, sizeWithGuardPages);

    void* result;
    if (InterlockedIncrement(&priorityForUnderrun) % 2)
        result = (void*)((size_t)(ptr) + pageSize);
    else 
        result = (void*)(((size_t)(ptr) + sizeWithGuardPages - pageSize - size) / sizeof(size_t) * sizeof(size_t)); 

    return result;
}   

void operator delete (void* ptr) 
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
    DWORD OldProtect;

    VirtualQuery(ptr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi));
    // leave pages in reserved state, but free the physical memory
    VirtualFree(mbi.AllocationBase, 0, MEM_DECOMMIT);
    // protect the address space, so noone can access those pages
    VirtualProtect(mbi.AllocationBase, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_NOACCESS, &OldProtect);
}
```