# a bizarre "Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint."?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

just don't tell me google that, because I did it for the last 48 hours.
this is my problem; I create a lon program, which execute many itterations; but in few itterations, this error comes ...

```
Critical error detected c0000374
Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
The program '[4452] Project.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

so, Visual Studio 2012 opens newaop.cpp; which contains few line

```
// newaop -- operator new[](size_t) REPLACEABLE
#include <new>

void *__CRTDECL operator new[](size_t count) _THROW1(std::bad_alloc)
     {  // try to allocate count bytes for an array
return (operator new(count));
}

/*
 * Copyright (c) 1992-2007 by P.J. Plauger.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
 V5.03:0009 */
```

pointing to the return line...
I searched so many; but nothing works; the problem in that, my program works for few itterations
I tried to locate the instructions generating this erreor (with cout's) and I found this loop

```
for (int i = OriginalCadre.X.x + 1; i < OriginalCadre.X.x + OriginalCadre.height; i++){
            for (int j = OriginalCadre.X.y + 1; j < OriginalCadre.X.y + OriginalCadre.width; j++){
                QuantityColor[Pattern_init[i][j]] ++;
            }
        }
```

this loop works at the begening for few itterations; which is bizarre !

Comment: you're likely corrupting the heap with that error (just an observation at this point)

Comment: Please provide us definition of QuanitiyColor and Patter_init.

Comment: are you freeing any memory above the loop by the way?

Comment: int* QuatityColot;
int** Pattern;

Comment: @BiLLiXx are you allocating memory inside those arrays? You declared some pointer but there's no memory initially inside it yet

Comment: Are those the two arrays you are using in your code samples btw? To clarify are those two seperate arrays you are using `delete` on or are those the arrays you are using in your for loop above

Comment: Of course, but this loop is at the begining of the itteration, those arrays are locals to the itteration, and if I know well, they'll be free at the end of each itteration ?

Answer (score 2):

`Critical error detected c0000374` is a sign of heap corruption, which means you might be doing bad things with memory e.g. writing after the end of a buffer, or writing to a buffer after it's been freed back to the heap.

I don't see any tell tale signs in that small loop, but likely you are writing past the memory location of QuantityColor or something similar.

[Debugging heap corruption errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010811/1409312)

Comment: Ok, I'll see it! but the thing,  tis this loop is not allocating memory, and it is athe begining of itteration, anyway, I'll see !

Comment: is Application Verfier compatible just with VS 2008;2005 ?