# Writing into stream passed to a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I have an issue writing into a stream, passed as a FILE* to a function which is contained in a DLL. Compiler: Visual C++, all versions 2005 to 2015. The precise errors vary; the VS 2015 version is given below. The problem is identical for Win32 and x64 targets.

Trying to boil down the problem, consider this function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void TestPrintf(FILE *TestFile)
{
    fprintf(TestFile, "Hello World");
}
```

Now, another function will be calling the above function in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void TestPrintf(FILE *TestFile);
void AnyFunction( void )
{
    FILE *TestFile;
    fopen_s( &TestFile, "PrintTest.txt", "wt");
    TestPrintf(TestFile);
}
```

The first function is part of a DLL. Depending on  the settings in
Properties /  C/C++  / Code Generation   during compilation of both the DLL and the program containing the caller, I get the following error messages:

Caller compiled for Multithread Debug (static):
    DLL compiled for either Multithread Debug (static) or Multithread Debug DLL:

```
    Debug assertion failed   
    File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp  
    Line: 980  
    Expression: __acrt_first_block == header
```

DLL compiled for Multithread (static):

```
    Debug assertion failed in the same file as before, but now  
    Line: 892  
    Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->block_use)
```

DLL compiled for Multithread DLL:

```
    Again another variant of the same. Now it is:  
    Line: 888  
    Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

Caller compiled for Multithread Debug DLL:
    DLL compiled for either Multithread (static) or Multithread Debug (static):

```
    same messages as above
```

DLL compiled for Multithread DLL:

```
    Yet another variant of the same. Now it is:  
    HEAP[FilePrintTest.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 
    01060000, 0107B7A0 )
```

DLL compiled for Multithread Debug DLL:

```
    This is error-free.
```

Caller compiled for Release (either Multithread or Multithread DLL):

```
all four versions of the DLL go error-free.
```

The difference between VS versions seems to be that VS 2015 first writes the output as intended and crashes afterwards, whereas VS 2005 crashes already while writing the output.

If the function **TestPrintf** is not in a DLL, but in a static library, there is no such problem (of course, there will be linker messages about library collisions, but the test program works nonetheless). However, unfortunately, I do need the writing function inside the DLL, and I must be able to call it from anywhere.

All of the above applies also to the case that the caller is in a console programme and the stream is *stdout*.

So my question is: Is there a stupid mistake on my side? If not, is there a way to work around this problem?

I would be grateful for suggestions!
Martin

Comment: Please, choose between C and C++. There are different languages

Comment: @Garf365: "Compiler: Visual **C++**"

Comment: @Olaf but code presented seams C

Comment: @Garf365: Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics!

Comment: @Olaf agree with you, but we don't know what want OP

Comment: @Garf365: To say it very clearly (I tought my first comment already was): If you use a C++ compiler, it **is** C++. You cannot use C semantics or C-only features then.

Comment: Clearly, someone's corrupting your heap, possibly by overriding some dynamically allocated buffer. The errors you see are printed when they are detected, which isn't necessarily when they are caused. I'd suggest looking for heap errors in general, you can find some suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1010106/26039).

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

Comment: @eran: I understand that. However, in the simplified example I posted, there is really nothing else I am doing than calling the function with the fprintf command. So it must be the very buffer memory of the FILE which is corrupted by fprintf, if the latter is called from within the DLL.

Comment: @Garf365: It is the same in C or C++. To make the example simple, I posted only C code.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the `fopen_s` syntax.  You are passing a `FILE * *` by using the `&` in front of the pointer.

Try removing the `&` symbol:
`fopen_s(TestFile, /*...*/);`

Your `TestFile` is already a pointer:

```
FILE * TestFile;
```

Your usage doesn't match the syntax presented by [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen)

Comment: Microsoft requires the syntax with a FILE** variable passed, see <a href="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx">here.</a>. This makes sense as a variable of type FILE* must be written. The old fopen did it by returning a value of type FILE*. I humbly suspect there is a typo in cppreference.com.

Comment: @Martin cppreference documents pointer to pointer to FILE for the first parameter of fopen_s