# why It works the debug build but the release only when I run it in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I guess the question can't be answerd but at least a advice where I should search. My application works perfecly in debug build and release build inside VS2010, but when I run the release build hangs in a particular point (I don't know where) but the debug exe dose not hang.

When I run the release build in a Win 7 do not hang only in win XP. What could be the difference between the the two build that that make not work properly?

I know is too few info, but I don't know what I should say or can. I can't give the entire code, that why I make the question so general and hope someone know so well the differences between the two builds that could show me the way.

I am using only one static library of mine, might be importan.

**UPDATE:**

All computers in win 7 64bits works fine all computers in Win xp 32bits don't. The build is 32bits

Comment: put a break point and look for the code :D

Comment: Declaring variables and not initializing them sometimes causes behavior like this

Comment: In VS2010 works I can't make brake points to check what it do inside.

Comment: I is not initialize variables, 1) should not get a warning about it? 2) the error should once on a while work in win xp and once while don't work in win 7?

Comment: Could be lots ot things... Maybe preprocessors on _DEBUG or NDEBUG. Or a classic is to put code in a ASSERT macro, like ASSERT(DoSomething()) to test the result of DoSomething. Then in release, DoSomething is no longer executed. Could be some memory initialization forgotten. You can try printing logs, either to StdOut or in a file if you are not able to debug the release build (which should be doable if you add debug symbols to your release build)

Comment: I only do this `#ifndef NDEBUG system("pause"); #endif` the other thing I do not do

Comment: possible duplicate of [/MT and /MD builds crashing, but only when debugger isn't attached: how to debug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811951/mt-and-md-builds-crashing-but-only-when-debugger-isnt-attached-how-to-debug)

Comment: There are an endless number of possible explanations.  You won't narrow it down until you get a debugger to look at the process.  You can make this as easy or as hard as you want, depending on how much work you do to get a testable install of XP.  The quickest way is to create a minidump of the hung process, a .dmp file, and open it on your dev machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be different behavior of the heap when the program is started from the debugger. Check this question, and the answer: [Differences between running an executable with Visual Studio debugger vs without debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16696444/395718)

Answer (score 0):

Since, you are saying your Win7 machines are 64 bit (which are working fine). Is it possible that you have got something in your project which is specifically targeting 64 bit ? i.e. some third party tool?

If not, you can build the solution to target specifically for 32 bit.
In your solution properties pages, go to "configuration" tab. Here for select "Release" in the configuration drop-down and in platform select "x86", see if this helps

-Milind